# Vuetify v-container with fill-height items alignment

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm new to Vue and Vuetify and this is probably something obvious, but I'm googling it for over an hour and I'm still stupid.
So basically I want to create wrapper using full height of viewport with one element aligned top, and one bottom (This will be inside v-navigation-drawer, few buttons on top and one bottom)

Here's sample code

```html
 <v-container fluid fill-height>
   <v-row align="start">
     <v-col>I want this to align Top</v-col>  
   </v-row>
   <v-row align="end">
     <v-col>And this to align Bottom</v-col>  
   </v-row>
 </v-container>
```

And this is how it looks https://codepen.io/rafal_w/pen/ExXeeWm

As you can see fill-height tag positions elements evenly with margins, and align tag on elements doesn't work. What do i do wrong?

Comment: You don't want to use ``css`` at all?

Comment: I think i will have to in the end, but now im just curious why doesnt it work, it supposed to according to docs

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so instead of align tag on child items, i was supposed to use align-self-start and align-self-end classes

https://codepen.io/rafal_w/pen/WNOaXVL

```
  <v-container fluid fill-height>
    <v-row class="align-self-start">
      <v-col>I want this to align Top</v-col>  
    </v-row>
    <v-row class="align-self-end">
      <v-col>And this to align Bottom</v-col>  
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This gets me all the time when I try to align items in full-height containers :-P The combination of classes and properties to align stuff in Vuetify is really not intuitive to me ...

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the better way to do this with Vuetify is the following:

```html
<v-app id="app">
  <v-card height="1000">
    <v-app-bar
      color="red"
      dense
      fixed
      flat
      dark
    >
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <span>Align Top</span>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    </v-app-bar>
  </v-card>
  <v-bottom-navigation fixed color="green">
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <span>Align Bottom</span>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
  </v-bottom-navigation>
</v-app>
```

Comment: I simplified my example. I know i could use v-app-bar and v-footer if it was main workspace. But i want it to be inside side navigation bar, thats why i used v-container with v-row/v-col